# Trying to remove item based on ID in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

My goal is to remove an item based on the ID. Here is the code I currently have:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> RemoveTodoItem(int id)
{
    // TODO
    // Use EFCore to remove the item based on id

    var todoItem = await _context.TodoItems.FindAsync(id);

    if (todoItem == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    _context.TodoItems.Remove(todoItem);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return NoContent();
}
```

My issue is that `TodoItems` keeps returning the error code CS1061, saying `TodoContext` does not contain a definition of `TodoItems`.

Here is the code I have in `TodoContext`:

```
public class TodoContext: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Todo> Todos { get; set; }

    public TodoContext(DbContextOptions<TodoContext> options) : base(options) {   }
}
```

`Todo` class:

```
public class Todo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsComplete { get; set; }
}
```

How could I fix this error?

I'm not sure if this has to do with dependency injection? I believe the database has already been injected to the controller.

Comment: Your `DbSet` property is called `Todos`? If you know the entity exists, you can skip the `.Find`; `_context.Todos.Remove(new Todo{Id = id});` But you'll have to handle the error.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Not entirely sure what you mean. I can remove     .FindAsync(id)     and the entire line of _context.Todos.Remove(new Todo{Id = id});?

Comment: Could you please include your `Todos` POCO class as well? So that it would easy to inveestigate your issue.

Comment: I have checked your shared snippet and tested in following way which working as expected. Be double check your, controller constructor and DbContextName and program.cs I assuming causing the error. However, you can refer to my solution to make sure you haven't miss anything.

Answer (score 1):

> My issue is that TodoItems keeps returning the error code CS1061.
> Saying TodoContext does not contain a definition of TodoItems

Actually, you might get the error for numerous reasons. For instance, if you don't [initialize the `TodoContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-7.0#create-the-database-context) while your [controller being called](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-7.0#create-controller-and-views). Even, if you write the name [with typos.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs1061#example)

In additional,  if you don't set primary key on your table or POCO class or if correct `dbContext` has not been passed while initialize the [`builder.Services.AddDbContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-7.0#register-the-schoolcontext) within your `program.cs` file these also can cause the issue.

> I'm not sure if this has to do with dependency injection? I believe
> the database has already been injected to the controller.

Although, you haven't shared your full controller class along with your constructor. Thus, I have tried following way along with your code snippet and its working as expected. Please have a look if you have implemented the same way.

Model:

```
public class Todo
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string? Name { get; set; }

    public bool IsComplete { get; set; }
}
```

DbContext:

```
public class TodoContext: DbContext
{
    public TodoContext(DbContextOptions<TodoContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
       
    public DbSet<Todo> TodoItems { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Todo>().ToTable("TodoItems");
    }
}
```

**Note:** I have set the table name as `TodoItems` in database.

`Program.cs` file:

```
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<TodoContext>(x => x.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
```

**Note:** Be sure, you have configure your database and server name in your [`appsettings.json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-7.0#register-the-schoolcontext) file.

Controller:

```
public class TodoController : Controller
{
    private readonly TodoContext _context;

    public TodoController(TodoContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
       
    [HttpDelete]
    public async Task<IActionResult> RemoveTodoItem(int id)
    {
        var todoItem = await _context.TodoItems.FindAsync(id);
        _context.TodoItems.Remove(todoItem);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return NoContent();
    }
}
```

**Note:** Make sure you have initialize the `TodoContext` within your [controller constructor.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-7.0#create-controller-and-views) Apparently, the error pointing this or please check if you have type the name correctly.

Output:

[image]

**Note:** If you would like to know more details on [Delete or Removing items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/crud?view=aspnetcore-7.0#update-the-delete-page) you could [check our official document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/crud?view=aspnetcore-7.0#update-the-delete-page)